# Google chrome/chromium browser does not work with x2go client side. Fix needed?

Tags: 18.04, chromium, proxy, x2go

I am using x2go to access my Ubuntu system remotely. The x2go server is running on Ubuntu 18.04 and I using x2go client on Windows 10.
Google chrome and chromium browsers both work fine when using the Ubuntu system, as well as Firefox. However, when I use the chrome/chromium browser using x2go, they do not work. I get the following error:

[image: Site unreachable error]

And then I redirected to the following error:

[image: No internet - error message]

Firefox works fine. `sudo apt-get package-name` works fine (under proxy). I am using proxy (password protected) and have used

```
export {http,https}_proxy=http://username:password@domain:port
```

but with no success. Also, I can not change the proxy settings of chrome from settings as it says that system proxy settings are used.

Both Chrome and Firefox use system proxy settings but Firefox works while Chrome doesn't. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: That reads as a problem with x2go on Windows 10

Comment: Could you clarify that please?
How come firefox works fine?
And what fix would you suggest?